# QR scanner time in

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I'm using a zxing core 1.7, zxing j2se 1.7 and webcam capture 0.3.11 libraries

may IDE is netbeans 7.2 and **mysql** for the database

The problem is the thread....i cant seem to make an identifier to break and jump it to another method...and i think im doing it very wrong...
any ideas ? T_T

```
 public void run() {
     do {
         try {
             Thread.sleep(300);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
         Result result = null;
         BufferedImage image = null;
         if (webcam.isOpen()) {
             if ((image = webcam.getImage()) == null) {
                 continue;
             }
             LuminanceSource source = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(image);
             BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
             try {
                 result = new MultiFormatReader().decode(bitmap);
             } catch (NotFoundException e) {
             }
         }
         int a;
         a = (result.getText().length()); //thread error
         if (result != null) {
             txtID.setText(result.getText());
             try {
                 QRLOAD();
             } catch (Exception e) {} //method to load jtable        
             try {
                 Update_PIC();
             } catch (Exception e) {} //method to load picture jlabel
             try {
                 Time_inUP();
             } //method to to update the time
             catch (Exception e) {}
             if (a > 1) {
                 OperatorQR(); //method to close the thread and call the main panel
             } else {
             }
         }
     } while (true);
 }
```

Comment: please explain what you meant by `make an identifier to break and jump it`..

Comment: @redflar3
ok im not good either in terms....i generated a QR code..the value is 1 digit....so its easy to scan...scanning it will generate a value to a jtextfield key released..generating the jtable view and followed by picture method...
i cant seem to halt it or stop it to validate it...it goes straight to the operator method killing the window....
i think i need a identifier or specifier  to make the first try catch to return its results and only ends by the method of the operator...

Comment: i try convert the result as int giving a thread error "CaptureCode.run(CaptureCode.java:817)"

Answer (score 0):

I my self figured the answer..hehe
setting the result as a int and getting the length will not work...
you will only indicate it in the if parameter...T_T

```
public void run() {

    do {

    try {


            Thread.sleep(300);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }

        Result result = null;
        BufferedImage image = null;

        if (webcam.isOpen()) {

            if ((image = webcam.getImage()) == null) {
                continue;
            }

            LuminanceSource source = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(image);
            BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));

            try {

                 result = new MultiFormatReader().decode(bitmap);



            } catch (NotFoundException e) {



            }

        }


        if ( result != null  ) {


                                txtID.setText(result.getText());




                                         try{QRLOAD();}    //method to load jtable
                                      catch(Exception e){ }                 

                                try{Update_PIC();}          //method to load picture jlabel
                                   catch(Exception e){ }


                              try{Time_inUP();}        //method to to update the time
                          catch(Exception e){ }       

                         try{Update_PIC();}
                            catch(Exception e){ }          

                                try{QRLOAD();}
                           catch(Exception e){ }




                              if (result.getText().length()>1 ) {// This is the solution 


                                OperatorQR();  //method to close the thread,webcam and call the main panel

    } 

                    }


    }while (true);



}
```